# How to get Google auth code parallelly with 'profileObj' and 'tokenObj' using"react-google-login" tool?

Tags: reactjs, access-token, google-signin

I am using *react-google-login* (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login) tool to sign in with Google. There are some issues:

- GoogleLogin gives me two type of object: `profileObj` and `tokenObj`. In 'tokenObj' I can get `access_token` and so on.
- If I use `accessType = 'code'` I can get the `auth_code`. But this prevents me getting the `profileObj` and `tokenObj`.
- Documentation says if use `accessType = 'permission code'` then I can get both the `tokenObj` and `auth_code`. But its not true. This is not happening.

Now I want to get both `tokenObj` and `auth_code`.

Is it really possible to do so? How can I get the `auth_code` parallelly with `profileObj` and `tokenObj`?